# How to change the voice of google tts

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-speech-api

I'm currently using the url below,
If the language is ko, the male voice, if en, only the female voice.
I want to unify it with a female voice.

- http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&total=1&idx=0&textlen=32&client=tw-ob&q=hello%20world%20&tl=en

- http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&total=1&idx=0&textlen=32&client=tw-ob&q=hello%20world%20&tl=ko

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The similar questions to change tts voice from male to female or the other way around have been asked numerous times. Unfortunately, Google doesn't support this yet.

There are many existing requests already on Google Translate Forum:
https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!forum/translate

You can follow any existing post or create a new one if you wish.